# Validating values

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have a list of values stored, I need to compare each value with each column cell in a data frame, if its found then place a value of "YES" in a Key column:

```
dep_list = df_epl[['Values']].copy()
dep_list = dep_list.dropna()
dep_list = dep_list.drop_duplicates()
dlist = dep_list['Values'].tolist()

df_existing['Key'] = ""
for l in dlist:
    for index, row in df_existing.iterrows():
        if row['Code'] == l:
            row['Key'] = "YES"
        else:
            pass
```

Everything is working except when writing "YES" value into the Key column. I have tried a lot of ways and it just don't work.

Comment: Is the condition `row['Key'] == l` ever true? Print `l` and `row['Key']` before to check that they are ever the same

Comment: Is `df_existing['Key'].apply(lambda x: any(i == x for i in dlist)).sum()` greater than 0?

Comment: Yes, I have validated manually that they match plenty of times, I have done the print and everything is just that writing "YES" into the Key column is not working

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are comparing `row['Key']` to `l`, where the former is always `""` as its defined immediately before the for loop.

I am guessing you actually meant to write `if row['Values'] == l`?

And with pandas you can actually use the following to check if your column value is inside a list:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': range(10)})

list_to_check = [1,2,3]

# create Key
df1['Key'] = 'No'
df1.loc[df1['value'].isin(list_to_check), 'Key'] = 'YES'

df1
```

Returns:

```
  value Key
0   0   No
1   1   YES
2   2   YES
3   3   YES
4   4   No
5   5   No
6   6   No
7   7   No
8   8   No
9   9   No
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.apply` should work fine

```
import pandas as pd

# assuming dlist is a list of strings
dlist = ["aa", "bb"]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["X","Y","Z"], data=[["a","c","b"],["c","bb","aa"]])

print(df)

   X   Y   Z
0  a   c   b
1  c  bb  aa

df["key"] = ""


df["key"] = df.apply(lambda x: "Yes" if any([y in dlist for y in x.values]) else "", axis=1)

print(df)

   X   Y   Z  key
0  a   c   b     
1  c  bb  aa  Yes
```